# Docker containers able to communicate in one subnet but not the other

Tags: networking, docker

When I put my Docker containers in subnet 192.168.124.0/24, they can communicate. If I put them in 192.168.123.0/24, they can't. Both times the applications are configured correctly for the IPs, literally the only thing that is different is the subnet the addresses are from.

Output of route

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         the.gateway 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp9s0
10.0.0.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp10s0.500
10.215.60.0     *               255.255.254.0   U     0      0        0 enp9s0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp10s0.700
172.17.0.0      *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.120.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp10s0.700
192.168.130.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp10s0.300
224.0.0.0       *               240.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 enp10s0.700
```

Output of iptables -L

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.5           tcp dpt:8888
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.11          tcp dpt:2002
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.11          tcp dpt:2001
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.11          tcp dpt:cisco-sccp

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

From these I can't see any problem. What could the issue be and how can I find out / fix it? The host is an Ubuntu 16.04